# product= $\exp\left[\frac{47\mathrm G}{30\pi}+\frac34\right]\left(\frac{11^{11}3^3}{13^{13}}\right)^{1/20}\sqrt{\frac{3}{7^{7/6}\pi}\sqrt{\frac2\pi}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, alternative-proof, infinite-product, constants

$\mathrm G$ is Catalan's constant.

I recently found the product 
$$
\alpha=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{E_n(\frac12)E_n(\frac7{12})E_n(\frac1{20})E_n(\frac{13}{20})}{E_n(\frac14)E_n(\frac1{12})E_n(\frac3{20})E_n(\frac{11}{20})}=\\
\exp\left[\frac{47\mathrm G}{30\pi}+\frac34\right]\sqrt{\frac{33}{91\pi}\sqrt{\frac2\pi\frac{\sqrt[5]{11}}{\sqrt[3]{7}}\sqrt[5]{\frac{3^3}{13^{3}}}}}$$
(an alternate form of the product in the title)

Where $$E_n(x)=\frac{j(n+x)}{(en)^{2x}j(n-x)}\qquad x\in(0,1)$$
and $j(x)=x^x$.

> Could I have some numerical evidence, or better yet an alternate proof? My tools are limited to desmos, which cannot really handle infinite products. Thanks.

---

My Proof.

We define $$\mathrm L(x)=\frac1\pi\int_0^{\pi x}\log(\sin t)dt$$
And we use $$\sin t=t\prod_{n\geq1}\left(1-\frac{t^2}{\pi^2 n^2}\right)$$
To see that $$\log(\sin t)=\log(t)+\sum_{n\geq1}\log\frac{\pi^2n^2-t^2}{\pi^2n^2}$$
Then integrate both sides over $[0,x]$ to get 
$$\pi\mathrm L(x/\pi)=x(\log x-1)+\sum_{n\geq1}x\log\bigg(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2n^2}\bigg)-2x+\pi n\log\frac{\pi n+x}{\pi n-x}$$
$$\pi\mathrm L(x/\pi)=\log\left[\frac{j(x)}{e^x}\right]+\sum_{n\geq1}\log\left[\frac{j(\pi n+x)}{(e\pi n)^{2x}j(\pi n-x)}\right]$$
$x\mapsto \pi x$:
$$\pi\mathrm L(x)=\log\left[\frac{j(\pi x)}{e^{\pi x}}\right]+\sum_{n\geq1}\log\left[\frac{j(\pi n+\pi x)}{(e\pi n)^{2\pi x}j(\pi n-\pi x)}\right]$$
$$\mathrm L(x)=\log\left[\left(\frac\pi{e}\right)^xj(x)\right]+\sum_{n\geq1}\log E_n(x)$$
Then we define $$U(x)=\prod_{n\geq1}E_n(x)$$
To see that $$U(x)=\left(\frac{e}{\pi x}\right)^x\exp\mathrm L(x)$$
Where we used $$\sum_{n}\log(a_n)=\log\left[\prod_{n}a_n\right]$$
and the neat rules $$\log(a^b)=\log(e^{b\log a})=b\log a$$
$$\log(a)\pm b=\log\left(e^{\pm b}a\right)$$
to simplify the expressions. Next, we define 
$$P_{\mu,\nu}(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_\mu;b_1,b_2,\dots,b_\nu)=\frac{\prod_{i=1}^\mu U(a_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^\nu U(b_i)}$$
And we see that 
$$P_{\mu,\nu}(a_1,\dots,a_\mu;b_1,\dots,b_\nu)=\prod_{n\geq1}\frac{\prod_{i=1}^\mu E_n(a_i)}{\prod_{i=1}^\nu E_n(b_i)}$$
This gives $$P_{1,1}(x_1;x_2)=\left(\frac{e}{\pi}\right)^{x_1-x_2}\frac{j(x_2)}{j(x_1)}\exp\left[\mathrm L(x_1)-\mathrm L(x_2)\right]$$
Then we define $$\mathrm{T}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi x}\log(\tan t)dt=\mathrm L(x)-\mathrm L(x+1/2)-\frac12\log2$$ 
To get that 
$$P_{1,1}\left(x;x+\frac12\right)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}e}\,\frac{j(x+1/2)}{j(x)}\exp\mathrm T(x)$$
So we have 
$$P_{2,2}\left(x_1,x_2+\frac12 ;x_2,x_1+\frac12\right)=\frac{j(x_1+1/2)j(x_2)}{j(x_2+1/2)j(x_1)}\exp\left[\mathrm T(x_1)-\mathrm T(x_2)\right]$$
Then using the identities 
$$\mathrm L(1/2)=-\frac12\log2$$
$$\mathrm L(1/4)=-\frac{\mathrm G}{2\pi}-\frac14\log2$$
We get $$P_{1,1}\left(\frac12;\frac14\right)=\frac1{(2\pi)^{1/4}}\exp\left[\frac{\mathrm G}{2\pi}+\frac14\right]\tag{1}$$
From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/987972/583016), the identity
$$-\mathrm T(1/12)=\frac{2\mathrm G}{3\pi}$$
which gives
$$P_{1,1}\left(\frac7{12};\frac1{12}\right)=\sqrt{\frac6{7\pi\sqrt[6]{7}}}\exp\left[\frac{2\mathrm G}{3\pi}+\frac12\right]\tag{2}$$
Then from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1848537/583016), the identity
$$\mathrm T(1/20)-\mathrm T(3/20)=\frac{2\mathrm G}{5\pi}$$
gives $$P_{2,2}\left(\frac1{20},\frac{13}{20};\frac3{20},\frac{11}{20}\right)=\left(\frac{j(11)j(3)}{j(13)}\right)^{1/20}\exp\frac{2\mathrm G}{5\pi}\tag{3}$$
Then multiplying $(1),(2),$ and $(3)$, we have the desired result, namely
$$P_{4,4}\left(\frac12,\frac7{12},\frac1{20},\frac{13}{20};\frac14,\frac1{12},\frac3{20},\frac{11}{20}\right)=\alpha$$

Comment: Were you ask a question? or just write a proof?

Comment: See the edit. My question is highlighted in yellow

Comment: @Mr.N what are you asking? $$\mathrm L(x)=\frac1\pi\int_0^{\pi x}\log(\sin t)dt...$$

Comment: @Mr.N yes. This is all my own work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked the same question on Math Overflow, and I got an answer in the affirmative. [Check it out.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/326156/130062)

Answer (score 4):

Here's a partial answer. Let me start with expressing my astonishment about the construction of such a complicated product, and even more about the closed expression you have found. Truely Ramanujan-like!

§1 Definitions (in Mathematica)

The auxiliary function

```
fe[n_, x_] := (n + x)^(n + x)/((E n)^(2 x) (n - x)^(n - x))
```

The partial product (up to the nn-th factor)

```
p[nn_] := 
 Product[(fe[n, 1/2] fe[n, 7/12] fe[n, 1/20] fe[n, 13/20])/(
  fe[n, 1/4] fe[n, 1/12] fe[n, 3/20] fe[n, 11/20]), {n, 1, nn}]
```

The closed expression result given in the OP

```
pr = Exp[(47 Catalan)/(30 \[Pi]) + 3/4] Sqrt[
   33/(91 \[Pi]) Sqrt[2/\[Pi] 11^(1/5)/7^(1/3) (3^3/13^3)^(1/5)]];

N[pr] = 0.780459...
```

§2 Check of numerics

Numerically, the product is slowly going down to `pr`

For instance `N[p[100]/pr-1] = 0.0013684`

§3 Sum over $\log(E_n)$

This is the elementary constituent of the ($\log$) of the product.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(E_n(x)) = \zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,1-x)-\zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,x+1)+x+x (-(\log (2)+\log (\pi )))$$

Here $\zeta ^{(1,0)}(s,z) = \frac{\partial}{\partial s}\zeta(s,z)$.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

$\displaystyle U(-x)=\left(\frac{2\pi |x|}{e}\right)^x \exp\left(\frac{Cl_2(2\pi x)}{2\pi}\right)~~$ for $~~|x|<1~~$ , $~~Cl_2(z) $ is the [Clausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function) function

$\displaystyle \alpha = \prod\limits_{x\in\{-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{7}{12},-\frac{1}{20},-\frac{13}{20},\\\hspace{5mm}+\frac{1}{4},+\frac{1}{12},+\frac{3}{20},+\frac{11}{20}\}} U(-x)~~~~$ with $~~~~\displaystyle \sum\limits_{x\in\{-\frac{1}{2},-\frac{7}{12},-\frac{1}{20},-\frac{13}{20},\\\hspace{5mm}+\frac{1}{4},+\frac{1}{12},+\frac{3}{20},+\frac{11}{20}\}} Cl_2(2\pi x) = \frac{47}{15}G$

*The rest of the product is just simple multiplication.*